# Matplotlib scroll_event not working with GTK3Agg backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouseevent

I'm trying to run [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/image_slices_viewer.html). It's supposed to display a plane from a 3D image, and scroll through the stack based on the user's scroll events on the mouse wheel.

It works fine with TkAgg (on Ubuntu and Windows), but it doesn't do anything with GTK3Agg (on Fedora). Apparently this is a [reported issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2668).

Has anyone found a way to work around this? I'd like to implement scroll zoom.